# Siddihi Pattern only trigger once

Tags: wso2, pattern-matching, streaming, complex-event-processing, siddhi

The introduction of Siddihi:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP300/Introduction+to+Siddhi+Query+Language

I write a pattern like below:

```html
from every( e1=TempStream[ruleid==1] ) -> e2=TempStream[ruleid==2 and sip==s1.sip and dip==s1.dip]
    within 10 min
select e1.sip,e1.dip,e1.ruleid
insert into AlertStream;
```

and my input data like below:

```html
sip dip ruleid
1.1 1.2 1
1.1 1.2 1
1.1 1.2 2
```

I expect the output like this:

```html
sip dip ruleid
1.1 1.2 1
1.1 1.2 1
```

but the cep output like this:

```html
sip dip ruleid
1.1 1.2  1
```

It seems that the Siddhi pattern trigger only once and the pattern only match the first input and the third input. The second input data has been ignored.

Is there any way to change the pattern to get my expect output ?

Comment: Your expected output is correct and you should get two resulting events. I just tried the same query you have given here with few modifications and I got the exact expected result. How are you viewing the results? Are you using Siddhi as a library or WSO2 CEP or WSO2 SP. If so what is the version?

Comment: It may be a bug in siddhi 4.3.0 or higher. Siddhi 4.2.20 works well and print the expected result.
I have written this issue in the github of Siddhi.

Comment: This is fixed with Siddhi version 4.3.10 onwards

Answer (score 0):

Expected output is correct and buggy behavior is corrected from Siddhi version 4.3.10 onwards